# Produce Audio with Convolutional neural networks

Tags: audio, deep-learning, theano, keras

**Were there any approaches on Producing Audio with Convolutional neural networks?**

There are a lot of approaches on producing images through convnets. But i see no articles or posts about producing audio.

According to this topic on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471072/convolutional-neural-network-cnn-for-audio) , the post writer says :

> "I have found out the audio can be represented as spectrograms."

**So why cant it be done?**

**To do this with Convnets, should I :**

**a)** Use LSTM with the conv layers?

**B)** What should be the output? Considering the spectogram...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course there is, WaveNet by Deepmind produces audio that is very similar to "human-like" quality. It can also generate music.

https://deepmind.com/blog/wavenet-generative-model-raw-audio/